# Removing a string from a list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I create a list, and I want to remove a string from it.

Ex:

```
>>> myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']   
>>> myList = myList.remove('c')
>>> print(myList)
None
```

What am I doing wrong here? All I want is `'c'` to be removed from `myList`!

Comment: Voting to close as this appears to be a typographical error

Comment: Actually even if he did do `myList = myList.remove('c')` it would cause same issue, so I guess we should not close it

Comment: you are using *one* method. you can consider reading the doc for that. (hint: in particular the return type)

Comment: Is there another function that would return the list with with the removed elements instead of modifying it in place and returning `None`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure what `a` is (I am guessing another list), you should do `myList.remove()` alone, without assignment.

Example -

```
>>> myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> myList.remove('c')
>>> myList
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

`myList.remove()` does not return anything, hence when you do `myList = <anotherList>.remove(<something>)` it sets myList to `None`

Answer (score 4):

Remember that lists are mutable, so you can simply call `remove` on the list itself:

```
>>> myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> myList.remove('c')
>>> myList
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

The reason you were getting `None` before is because `remove()` always returns `None`

Answer (score 1):

The `remove()` function doesn't return anything, it modifies the list in place.  If you don't assign it to a variable you will see that `myList` doesn't contain `c` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Anand's Answer,

```
mylist = mylist.remove('c')
```

The above code will return 'none' as the return type for my list. So you want to keep it as

```
mylist.remove('c')
```