# Using pop on a list containing a string

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
listA = ['1,2,3,4,5']
```

where it is in string format. I want to perform a simple function that removes the last digit in the string, which in this case would be 5 and print it out.

I've tried something

```
listA = ['1,2,3,4,5']
for i in listA:
    print(listA.pop())
```

What i tried is wrong as I'm not familiar with using pop on strings.

Comment: *Why* do you have that? Where does it come from? A list containing a single string that you actually want to be a list is a weird starting point. Have you considered converting the string into an actual list?

Comment: If you search how to remove an element from a list containing strings, you can use `remove()` as explained in [Removing a string from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077838/2641825):  `myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
myList.remove('c')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What you have is not a list of integers. It is a list with a single element, that element is a string of comma separated integers
2. You're not using `i`
3. You're iterating over the list and mutating it as you do so. Do *not* do this, because it does not give you the behaviour you expect.

I would recommend a `while` loop instead. First, fix your array.

```
listA = listA[0].split(',')
```

Now, iterate over it.

```
while listA:
    print(listA.pop())
```

You use the truthiness of a nonempty list to keep iterating over it. This removes all the digits. However, if you just want the last digit and nothing more, call `listA.pop()` only *once*.

---

If you don't want to fix your array, you should extract the last digit like this:

```
 listA = ['1,2,3,4,5']
 print(int(listA[0][-1]))  # [0] gets the string, [-1] gets the last character in the string
```

This is ungainly, so I recommend fixing your array instead.

Comment: @COLDSPEED thanks a bunch. Splitting the string in the list was brilliant!

Comment: @Electric Sure, happy to help. Everyone begins somewhere. In future I'd recommend thoroughly reading up on the docs so you're better prepared to do what you want :) Cheers.

Comment: "that element is a string of comma separated integers" : actually, it's a string of comma separated numeric characters ;) (ok nitpicking....)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is giving you the last character. You can also extract the last value using split which will break up text based on a defined delimiter:

```
listA = ['1,2,3,4,5']
print( listA[0].split(',')[-1] )
```