# How to parse through a list in Python using Regex

Tags: python, regex, nonetype

I am trying to parse through a list of 1400+ emails and each word is a part of the list. I'm using Python 3.4. I need to filter out the following words:

- The output should only contain words with letters that are are 4
  letters or longer (no numbers)
- The output should remove common words (stop words such as 'and', 'but', 'they', etc)
- The output should remove common words in the output
  that are not meaningful for the word cloud('sakai', 'email', 're: ').

Thus a sample list looks like the following:

```
    words = ['re:', 'sakai:', 'which', 'code', 'base', 'to', 'use', 'in', 
    'production:', 'maintenance', 'branch', 'or', 'release', 'tags']
```

My question is how do I eliminate the specified list items  from given 3 rules and remove them from words()?
I tried this:

```
import re

for word in words:
    pattern = re.match('*sample removing stop words*', word)
    try:
        if pattern:
            words = words.remove(word)
            continue
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

But every time I get a 'None', I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Therefore the words() list doesn't change. How can I change words() list to get rid of words specified above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a string from a list python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077809/removing-a-string-from-a-list-python)

Comment: It is generally no good idea to remove elements from a list where you iterate over in that moment. I suggest you collect all found words and delete them after finishing interating over words.

Comment: So are suggesting I filter out all the words i dont want, and then collect all the others?